# Problem with the date layout when importing a .csv file into a MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, csv

as I life in Germany the several hundred dates in my .csv file have another layout than the US-American dates as mine is 'DD-MM-YYYY' and I need to convert every single of them to 'YYYY-MM-DD'. Now to my question. How can I convert it? Right now I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

My used code at the moment (still working on it):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import pymysql

mydb = pymysql.connections.Connection(host='localhost', user='user', password='password', database='database', unix_socket="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock", port=3306)

cursor = pymysql.cursors.Cursor(mydb)

csv_data = csv.reader(file('wetterdaten_neu.csv'))

for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO sensoren(date,temp,gartemp,tempdallas,pressure,height,pressurenn,tempdallas2,humidity,taup)''VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',row)
    print row

mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print "CSV has been imported into the database"
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could change that line of your code:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO sensoren(date,temp,gartemp,tempdallas,pressure,height,pressurenn,tempdallas2,humidity,taup)''VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',row)
```

to:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO sensoren(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date, "%m-%d-%Y"), "%Y-%m-%d"),temp,gartemp,tempdallas,pressure,height,pressurenn,tempdallas2,humidity,taup)''VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',row)
```

Comment: I tried and there now is another error: ValueError: unsupported format character 'm' (0x6d) at index 53

Comment: So what about: cursor.execute('INSERT INTO sensoren(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date, \'%m-%d-%\'), \'%Y-%m-%d\'),temp,gartemp,tempdallas,pressure,height,pressurenn,tempdallas2,humidity,taup)''VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',row)

It's look like more python than mysql problem.

Comment: Unfortunately still the same error: ValueError: unsupported format character 'm' (0x6d) at index 53

Answer (score 0):

Before your call to `cursor.execute()`, you can convert the date value in `row` using the `datetime.strptime()`:

> # Using datetime.strptime()
>
> dt = datetime.strptime("21/11/06 16:30", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")

This will set dt = datetime.datetime(2006, 11, 21, 16, 30). You can then output whatever format you need for your database. Of course, you would replace the sample date string with your `row['date']` value.

The method for producing the formatted string would look like this:

```
dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

EDIT: For clarification, your code would look something like this:

```
import datetime
```

```
for row in csv_data:
    # First convert date string into a datetime object
    dt = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%d-%m-%Y")
    # Then save the correctly formatted date string back to the row array
    row[0] = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO sensoren(date,temp,gartemp,tempdallas,pressure,height,pressurenn,tempdallas2,humidity,taup) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',row)
    print row
```

Comment: My Problem is that there a are like a thousand rows of data with everyone having another date and i want to convert every single date to the wanted format

Comment: Are you saying that there are multiple different date formats in the incoming .csv file?

Comment: Several hundreds of dates but they all are in one format, wichich i have to change for every single one of them

Comment: @THORPEDO, I have added some sample code for clarification.